# Neo4j C# Client, null properties

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm having a strange issue with the neo4j c# client where the first query below works, but the 2nd query projection results in null properties. Any ideas?

```
var query = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
            .Match("(p:Phenotype)")
            .Return<PhenotypeSpeciesDTO>("p")
            .Results.ToList();

        var query = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
            .Match("(p:Phenotype)")
            .Return((p) => new
            {
                phenotypeName = p.As<PhenotypeSpeciesDTO>(),
            })
            .Results.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what the problem is - as when I run the following in LinqPad:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), "neo4j", "neo");
    //var client = new BoltGraphClient(new Uri("bolt://localhost:7687"), "neo4j", "neo");
    client.Connect();

    client.Cypher
                    .Match("(p:Phenotype)")
                    .Return<PhenotypeSpeciesDTO>("p")
                    .Results.ToList().Dump("Query 1");

    client.Cypher
        .Match("(p:Phenotype)")
        .Return((p) => new
        {
            phenotypeName = p.As<PhenotypeSpeciesDTO>(),
        })
        .Results.ToList().Dump("Query 2");
}


public class PhenotypeSpeciesDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

it works fine. 
The only thing I can notice is the queries are returning different structures, is it possible you want to do:

```cs
var query = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
            .Match("(p:Phenotype)")
            .Return((p) => p.As<PhenotypeSpeciesDTO>())
            .Results.ToList();
```

as this gives the same output as:

```cs
.Return<PhenotypeSpeciesDTO>("p")
```